# Populate listview with data received from SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am currently trying to populate a listview with some data I have pulled from my database table; but not sure where to start; I have tried the following:

```
lstData.DataSource = conn;
lstData.DataBind();
```

But that causes an error:

> "Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource,
>   IEnumerable, or IDataSource. MVC"

Am I using the correct query strings in order to populate my listview?

Thanks,

Callum

C# Code:

```
string ssConnectionString = "Server connection";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ssConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT Category FROM [dbo].[Category] WHERE CategoryID = '16'";            

command.ExecuteNonQuery();          

string com = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
lblSQL.Text = com;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Assigning an `SqlConnection` to `.DataSource` property is not logical. And your `ExecuteNonQuery` is meaningless. It doesn't do anything at all. What are you try to do exactly? And use _using statement_ to dispose your database connections

Comment: I am trying to get the information I pull from the SqlConnectionString into a listview via different controls.

Comment: `lstData.DataSource = conn;` is wrong `lstData.DataSource=aDataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as a base to start from you may want to try the following: I assume your connection in "Server connection" is a place holder for a real connection string and you know what should go there.

```
string ssConnectionString = "Server connection";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ssConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT Category FROM [dbo].[Category] WHERE CategoryID = '16'";     
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command); 
DataTable dataTable;
da.Fill(dataTable);   
lstData.DataSource = dataTable;
lstData.DataBind();
conn.Close();
```